# Strapi Hide Content Type

Tags: content-type, strapi

I've search for several hours how to hide a specific content type.

I found some post but they are too older and their solutions doesn't work in the actual's strapi.

For precisions, my collection type is declared inside a local plugin. I juste want to manage my collection inside the plugin page and I doesn't want it appear in the content type in the left menu.

If someone has a solution, it's can be really helpfull.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are working on this: https://github.com/strapi/rfcs/pull/22

But for now, based on official docs ([plugin customization](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/plugin-customization.html)), you can overwrite file in content-manager plugin.

**Be sure** to check this file on strapi updates to avoid overwriting important code.

1. Copy file `strapi-plugin-content-manager/services/data-mapper.js` from your app node_modules into `extensions/content-manager/services/`
2. Now edit this file in your project and add your content type to array `HIDDEN_CONTENT_TYPES` following this pattern: `plugins::[plugin-name].[content-type]`
   For example: `plugins::ecommerce.product`

```js
...

const HIDDEN_CONTENT_TYPES = [
  'plugins::upload.file',
  'plugins::users-permissions.permission',
  'plugins::users-permissions.role',
  'plugins::ecommerce.product',
];

...
```

Comment: It works, thank you very much! I really hope to see this feature in the future, it seems logical to me that some "option" pages are not manageable by users ...

Answer (score 11):

In new version of Strapi v3.6.6 — Community Edition there is an option in model

```json
{
  "kind": "collectionType",
  "collectionName": "test",
  "info": {
    "name": "test"
  },

  "options": {
    "increments": true,
    "timestamps": true,
    "draftAndPublish": true
  },

  **"pluginOptions": {
    "content-manager": {
      "visible": false
    }
  },**

  "attributes": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. I have been searching for this functionality for hours and you just solved my problem

Comment: Just what I was looking for!  goodKarma ++

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the plugin to make updates to the content-type's schema.

Copy the content-type schema from the plugin to your src folder.

In my case, I copied `/strapi-plugin-navigation/server/content-types/audience/schema.json` to `/src/extensions/navigation/content-types/audience/schema.json` (notice that the `strapi-plugin-` part of the folder name is removed) and added the following to it to hide the "Audience" content type from the content manager and content-type builder:

```
"pluginOptions": {
   "content-manager": {
     "visible": false
   },
   "content-type-builder": {
     "visible": false
   }
},
```

Official documentation [here](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/development/plugins-extension.html#extending-a-plugin-s-content-types).

Answer (score 1):

In Strapi v4 it is `"visible": false`

```
{
  "kind": "collectionType",
  "collectionName": "bookmark",
  "info": {
    "singularName": "bookmark",
    "pluralName": "bookmarks",
    "displayName": "Bookmark",
    "description": ""
  },
  "options": {
    "increments": true,
    "timestamps": true,
    "draftAndPublish": true
  },
  "pluginOptions": {},
  "attributes": {
    "index": {
      "type": "integer",
      "unique": false,
      "visible": false
    },
  }
}
```